# Cypress code coverage for cross-origin code

Tags: cypress, code-coverage, cypress-code-coverage, cypress-origin

Code fails when running with code coverage for cross-origin program

My program uses a lot of cross-origin testing and I'm able to get it to run fine, but when I try to add in code coverage I get an error when it tries to change origins that says 'Blocked a frame with origin "https://myurl.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.'. Is Cypress able to record code coverage if it changes domains during my tests?